Is the direct limit of flat homomorphisms flat?
I’m reading Lei Fu’s “Etale Cohomology Theory”.


Proposition 5.3.6. Let $X$ be a scheme, $s$ a geometric point in $X$, and $s’$ a geometric point of $\tilde X_s$. Denote the image of $s’$ in $X$ also by $s’$. Then $\tilde X_{s’}$ is $X$-isomorphic to the strict localization $(\tilde X_s)^{\tilde\;}_{s’}$ of $\tilde X_s$ at $s’$.




Proof. By 5.3.4, we have a canonical $X$-morphism $\tilde X_{s’}\to \tilde X_s$. From its construction, one can show this is a flat morphism……


In order to show the canonical $X$-morphism $\tilde X_{s’}\to \tilde X_s$ is a flat morphism, I extract the following question from the proof:
$(A_i,f_{ij})$ is a direct system of commutative rings, the direct limit of $(A_i,f_{ij})$ is $A$. $(B_i,g_{ij})$ is a direct system of commutative rings, the direct limit of $(B_i,g_{ij})$ is $B$. For each $i$, $\varphi_i: A_i\to B_i$ is flat, and $\varphi_i$ is compatible with $f_{ij}$ and $g_{ij}$. Is $B$ flat over $A$?

Try using that tensor products commute with filtered colimits. Are filtered colimits of exact sequences exact again?

@Thorgott I am not sure if that helps here. Your statements work over a fixed ring. Here, the base ring varies.

@MartinBrandenburg I checked again and I don't believe any of my statements fail over a varying base ring. Am I missing something?

We can use the following equational characterization of flatness (Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, Ch. I, § 2. Proposition 13, Corollary 1, or Stacks Project Tag 00HK):

An $A$-module $M$ is flat if and only for every linear relation $\sum_{i \in I} a_i x_i = 0$ in $M$ (with $a_i \in A$ and $x_i \in M$, where $I$ is finite) there exists a finite set $J$ and elements $(y_j)_{j \in J}$ in $M$ and elements $(a_{i,j})_{i \in I, j \in J}$ in $A$ such that $\sum_{i \in I} a_i a_{i,j} = 0$ for all $j \in J$ and $x_i = \sum_{j \in J} a_{i,j} y_j$ for all $i \in I$.

Now assume that a ring $A$ is the filtered colimit of rings $A^s$, that $M^s$ is a module over $A^s$ along with compatible maps $M^s \to M^{s'}$ for $s \leq s'$, linear over $A^s \to A^{s'}$, so that we can form the colimit $M$ of these, which is a module over $A$.
Claim. If each $M^s$ is flat over $A^s$, then $M$ is flat over $A$.
To show that $M$ is a flat $A$-module, take a linear relation $\sum_{i \in I} a_i x_i = 0$ in $M$. For a sufficiently large $s$, this comes from a linear relation in $M^s$ over $A^s$, that is, we may assume $a_i \in A^s$ and $x_i \in M^s$, and that the equation holds in $M^s$ (this follows from the construction of the filtered colimit). Since $M^s$ is supposed to be a flat module over $A^s$, there exists a finite set $J$ and elements $(y_j)_{j \in J}$ in $M^s$ and elements $(a_{i,j})_{i \in I, j \in J}$ in $A^s$ such that $\sum_{i \in I} a_i a_{i,j} = 0$ holds in $A^s$ for all $j \in J$ and $x_i = \sum_{j \in J} a_{i,j} y_j$ holds in $M^s$ for all $i \in I$. Then by applying the homomorphisms $A^s \to A$ and $M^s \to M$, these equations also hold in $A$ resp. $M$, and we are done. $\checkmark$
An alternative proof is given in the Stacks Project, Tag 05UU.

We can do this with the following lemma:
Under the assumptions given in your problem, $\text{colim}_i\text{Tor}_n^{A_i}(B_i,M)\cong \text{Tor}_n^A (B,M)$ for any $A$-module $M$.
Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Using the universal property of the direct limit, $M$ also inherits the structure of an $A_i$-module for each $i$ in a way that is compatible with the direct limit structure. Consider now the functor $F=(M\otimes_{A}(-))\circ\text{colim}_i=\text{colim}_i \circ (M\otimes_{A_i} (-))$. I'll leave this as an exercise to show that these are indeed equal.
Let $P_i\rightarrow B_i$ be a projective resolution. It is known that the directed colimit functor preserves projectives, thus we get a projective resolution $P:=\text{colim}_i P_i\rightarrow B$. Then $L_n F(B)$ is the homology of the sequence $F(P_i)\rightarrow F(B_i)$. By our first expression for $F$, this is the homology of the sequence:
$$M\otimes_A\text{colim}_i P_i\cong M\otimes _A P\rightarrow M\otimes_A \text{colim}_i B_i\cong M\otimes_A B$$
Which is precisely $\text{Tor}_n^A (M,B)$.
But by our other expression for $F$, $$L_n F=L_n(\text{colim}_i\circ (M\otimes_{A_i}(-)))\cong\text{colim}_i L_n (M\otimes_{A_i}(-))\cong\text{colim}_i\text{Tor}_n^{A_i}(M,-)$$ Since $\text{colim}_i$ is exact in the category $A$-mod. Thus $L_n F(B)\cong\text{colim}_i\text{Tor}_n^{A_i}(M,B)$
Thus $L_n F(B)\cong\text{Tor}_n^A(M,B)\cong\text{colim}_i\text{Tor}_n^{A_i}(M,B_i)$ for any $A$-module $M$, proving our claim.
Returning to the problem at hand, recall that an $R$-module $M$ is flat iff $\text{Tor}_n^R (M,-)=0$ for all $n$ (actually, this is true iff it is true for $n=1$). I'll let you prove the rest on your own using this fact and the lemma above!

The linked lemma is for directed systems $ {M_i}$ of $R$-modules with $R$ fixed. On the other hand, in this case, each $B_i$ is an $A_i$-module where $A_i$ varies. I suppose the proof would still work with modifications though…

Ope thank you for pointing this out! Also can be proven by noting that the directed colimit functor is left-adjoint and thus preserves projectives.

I edited my response to adjust for the initial oversight.

To define P=colimP_i, we need morphisms between the $P_i$’s. They have to be compatible with the $g_{ij}$’s. How do you construct them?

I believe the construction follows from the Comparison Theorem in homological algebra (Theorem 2.2.6 in Introduction to Homological Algebra by Weibel).
